# Transforming gson to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having trouble converting gson to JSON, using Google's library 'gson' library. I am using the Java Spark web framework, and ResponseTransformer is a part of the Spark lib. The model argument variable can be any POJO.

```
public class JsonTransformer implements ResponseTransformer {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public String render(Object model) {

        String json = null;
        if (model instanceof java.util.List) {
            model = ((java.util.List) model).get(0);
        }
        try {
            json = gson.toJson(model);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(5);
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

there is some sort of problem when model is a List object, the gson library is having trouble converting/serializing it to a json String.

So this is just a quick fix to try to debug this: I am trying to reassign model to the first element of the model List, if model is an instance of List. So this is more of a basic Java question... When I attempt to reassign model to the first element of model, Java is not letting that happen. Why is that so?

Also, if anyone knows why gson is failing so hard in this case, please LMK. This should not be happening. There is no obvious infinite recursion happening.

To prove it, here is the contents:

[image]

I get a infinite recursion stacktrace though:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)

the object I am trying to convert from a POJO to JSON looks like this:

```
public class Model {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private boolean done;
    private Date createdOn;

    public Model(BasicDBObject dbObject) {
        this.id = ((ObjectId) dbObject.get("_id")).toString();
        this.title = dbObject.getString("title") == null ? "placeholder title" : dbObject.getString("title");
        this.done = ((Boolean)dbObject.getBoolean("done")) == null ? false : dbObject.getBoolean("done");
        this.createdOn = dbObject.getDate("createdOn") == null ? new Date() : dbObject.getDate("createdOn");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the exception?

Comment: sure will add it to the question

Comment: There seems to be some sort of problem where the program attempts to set the id field of Model to an ArrayList instead of a String...it's weird

Comment: @AlexanderMills I'm running into the same problem right now (following the same/similar tutorial). Did you end up getting a solution?

Comment: yeah, I started using Node.js, it's a lot easier than Java, LOL

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `BasicDBObject` being a default constructor argument. 
Gson doesn't like it. Remove that and it will work. Read: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer

Comment: yeah but what can I substitute BasicDBObject for?

Comment: Just overload the constructor which is a no-op with no arguments. If you really want to force gson to use that constructor then you need to use custom JsonDeserializer and register with gson.

Comment: @AlexMills if the solution worked for you then can you please select the correct answer.